# How to wildcard a file name and run in bash?

Tags: bash, jar, spark-submit

I'm running a spark-submit with a target jar like this:

```
spark-submit --class com.Main  target/scala-2.11/myapp-0.0.1-assembly.jar
```

But the jar version can change, which will cause this command to fail. So I want to be able to wildcard that part of the file name and run, something like this:

```
spark-submit --class com.Main  target/scala-2.11/myapp-[anyversion]-assembly.jar
```

Is there some bash syntax that allows me to do that?

Comment: Escaping is used to make special characters be treated literally. I don't think that's what you really want.

Comment: You're right, I meant wildcard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a wildcard:

```
spark-submit --class com.Main  target/scala-2.11/myapp-*-assembly.jar
```

However, this will only work if there's just one file matching the pattern.